# getline + substr = slow first run?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc

I am using CodeBlocks on Windows with TDM-GCC compiler.

The problem is that when I combine `getline` and `substr` the first run is slow (takes some 15-16 seconds).

This is the slow case:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string test;
  ifstream file("test.txt");
  getline(file,test);
  test.substr(2);
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

These programs (posting main() only), on the other hand, run fast (~1 second on the first run):

```
{
  string test = "testing";
  ifstream file("test.txt");
  test.substr(2);
  file.close();
  return 0;
}

{
  string test;
  ifstream file("test.txt");
  getline(file,test);
  file.close();
  return 0;
}

{
  string test = "testing";
  ifstream file("test.txt");
  getline(file,test);
  test.substr(2);
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

So `getline` or `substr` are not slow on their own and the problem gets fixed if I initialize the string before `getline` (works also with `std::string test; test = "testing";`)

I will also point out that I am not talking about compile times but the **first run** of the executable. The **slow first run** condition is also true if I copy the executable to another location - it's slow for one first time in each new location. Other runs (of either **slow** or **fast** versions) takes less than 0.05s.

Can you explain this behaviour? Can you suggest another fix (some includes or compiler settings probably) to avoid this problem?

Comment: How big is your "test.txt" file? Does it contain at least one endline character?
BTW, since you specify std:: for string and ifstream, you should do also for getline

Comment: File can contain "firstline" (without endline) only or I can add other lines, it doesn't affect the behaviour. About std:: - it compiles (no warnings) like  this, it doesn't without any of these two. But I will change examples to use namespace :)

Comment: Are you sure the first program didn't load the file into the operating system file buffers (and thus incurred the cost of reading from disk, which is considerable), whereas the others found the data already present and did not have to read from disk again? And since you mention copying executables as making a difference, similar concerns apply. In the new location, the program has to be reread from disk, and maybe shared libraries resolved and loaded too, and this takes more time the first time than on subsequent executions. Did you try the 'fast' programs before the 'slow' one after a move?

Comment: You didn't tell us how large the file is... If it's all one long line, it can be substantially slow to read a file into memory the first time round (hard disks today deliver some 50-100MB/s sustained data rates, network file systems are slower typically - and of course, the data is probably on a disk somewhere).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That might be the case of "first run" in general, but the slow program is still slow even if any of the other programs are run just before.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I told in the comments - it doesn't matter if its one line of "testing" or multiple lines... Besides, all the other variants open file, too. And all but one does the getline and does it fast.

Comment: If it takes 15 seconds to fetch a file (and it's not the complete opposite side of the planet, and assuming you haven't written your own OS and Runtime library), there's something wrong externally to your program, I'd say. Most likely culprit is anti-virus software...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I suspect shared libraries too, but can I don't seem to include any. Can I test if some are included or force static includes only?

Comment: You will be using shared libraries for the C and C++ runtime. But I very much doubt they are THAT slow.

Comment: I noticed, that if I include outputs, I can see that nothing starts happening before ~15s pass. And secondly - yes and thanks @MatsPetersson - if I turn off Kaspersky, the problem is gone. Still this is strange because it's such a subtle change in the program, why would it trigger such an atention?

Comment: It's probably a bug in the AV software. I've seen it so many times It's getting boring... (And no, it doesn't matter which vendor of AV software you are using, they all do this sort of thing from time to time)

Comment: Ah, alright. If you care to write an answer, I will accept it :)